# One conda environment automatically takes other's dependencies in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have two conda environments named 'myenv' and 'newenv' and i installed tensorflow in myenv but not in newenv and in both environment i installed ipykernel using:
pip install ipykernel
and then :
python -m ipykernel install --user --name name_env --display-name "Python (name_env)"
I did this in both environment so that now i have 3 kernels in my jupyter notebook named: Python(myenv),Python(newenv),Python3 .
But when changed to kernel newenv and try to import tensorflow and it imports however i haven't installed tensorflow in newenv but when i tried to import it through comand terminal of newenv it shows error 'No module named tensorflow'.
Then why it imports in jupyter notebook not in command terminal?
Please help me to solve this issue.